# How i display the json array data from api

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

Below is my data get from API , I try to display the shopId, Shopname and shopcode but failed.Any one can help me solve this problem ? I am using the PHP to write the script and get API data.Below is my script to get API data.

```
   <?php      
    $get = file_get_contents("http://api.meirenji.cn/api/xxxxxxxxxxx");
    $json = json_decode($get);

    $shop_id = $json->content->shopId;
    echo "Shop ID : ".$shop_id."";
    ?>
```

Below is the data that i get from API, it have multiple array data, i nee get data shopId, Shopname,shopcode

```
stdClass Object
(
    [status] => 0
    [msg] => succes
    [content] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [shopId] => 6674
                    [shopname] => SP
                    [shopcode] => 38862185
                    [type] => shop
                    [flag] => 1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [shopId] => 6498
                    [shopname] => Adidas
                    [shopcode] => 74812597
                    [type] => shop
                    [flag] => 1
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [shopId] => 6498
                    [shopname] => Nike 
                    [shopcode] => 98741852
                    [type] => shop
                    [flag] => 1
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [shopId] => 6501
                    [shopname] => Puma
                    [shopcode] => 13847915
                    [type] => shop
                    [flag] => 1
                )

            [4] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [shopId] => 6509
                    [shopname] => Adidas NEO
                    [shopcode] => 26700485
                    [type] => shop
                    [flag] => 1
                )

            [5] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [shopId] => 6865
                    [shopname] => Testing Unit
                    [shopcode] => 23891935
                    [type] => shop
                    [flag] => 1
                )

            [6] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [shopId] => 9661
                    [shopname] => UNDER ARMOR
                    [shopcode] => 88741294
                    [type] => shop
                    [flag] => 1
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get **shopname** and **shopcode** from your response object, you've to loop over your **content** like this way using `foreach()`,

```
foreach($json->content as $key=>$row){
  echo "shopname = $row->shopname and shopcode = $row->shopcode". PHP_EOL; 
}
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/tWqt7

Comment: i got try , but got error come out  Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\meirenji\index.php on line 9
shotname= & shopcode =

Comment: Try with my updated answer again and let me know still you get error or not?

Comment: foreach($json->content as $row){ echo $row->shopId . "\n"; } i write like this , it is correct ?

Comment: same error also

Comment: make it like this `foreach($json->content as $key=>$row){ echo "shopname = $row->shopname and shopcode = $row->shopcode". PHP_EOL; 
}`

Comment: same problem bro , i try display shopid also cannot Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

Comment: @Lawrence I've added a demo for you to simulate your $json data. **Note** I've used the same code to get the contents like `shopid`, `shopname` and it works fine. If it doesn't work for you then you've some issue with your API response data.

Comment: bro , it work bro , tq very much